# How to fix "App Already Bootstrapped with this Element"?

Tags: angularjs, gwt, angular-ui-bootstrap

I just upgraded the Angular to 1.2.8.

I am initializing and opening a model from GWT using $wnd.angular.bootstrap($doc, ['fmEventLogApp']);

After closing the model, when I try to open the model again, it is trying to reinitialize the model again and throwing an error as "uncaught exception: com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses"

But when I see the actual error message, it says "App Already Bootstrapped with this Element".

How to solve this problem in case of a model window? Please help.